# Forcing the default language as per user settings for Guest user

Tags: customer-community

We have a multilingual site - when the guest user access the site the language displayed is based on the OS locale or browser language and if that language is supported by our site.  However, the language settings on the guest user are ignored!  Is there a way to make sure that the site is always displayed in the default language as set on the guest user settings?

So basically site should always be in English for the guest user regardless of OS or browser language settings.

Comment: Multilingual sites are managed using [configuration operations here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_languages_overview.htm&type=5). see Default Language option